# Disabling Nginx's proxy buffering doesn't synchronize the response

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

My understand on disabled Nginx's proxy buffering is that the app server will wait the client to respond instead of Nginx, so I should see many open connections, but it's not the case in my testing.

Setup:

```
client (10.2.0.7) <===> Nginx (10.2.0.5) <===> PythonApp (10.2.0.4, port 8000)
```

500 slow connections initiated by the client
`slowhttptest -c 500 -H -g -o my_header_stats -i 10 -r 50 -t GET -u http://pythonapp.com -x 24 -p 3`

Nginx Conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events
{
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http
{

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # gzip on;
    upstream pythonapp
    {
        server 10.2.0.4:8000;
    }

    proxy_buffering off;
    server
    {
        listen 80;
        proxy_buffering off;
        server_name pythonapp.com;

        location /
        {
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://pythonapp;
        }
    }

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Can only see 1 open connection from Nginx
[image: Only 1 open connection]

If I initiate slow connections from client to PythonApp server directly, I can see many open connections
Setup:

```
client (10.2.0.7) <===> PythonApp (10.2.0.4, port 8000)
```

500 slow connections initiated by the client
`slowhttptest -c 500 -H -g -o my_header_stats -i 10 -r 50 -t GET -u http://10.2.0.4:8000 -x 24 -p 3`
[image]

My questions are

1. Why my app server doesn't have many open connections after Nginx reverse-proxies it?
2. If my setting is incorrect, can you provide explicit code & config example to set up the corresponding environment, so as to show the performance or throughput difference between enabled remote buffering and disabled remote buffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to test the throughput difference of enabled/disabled proxy buffering. I think `slowtest` isn't a good tool to test it. I used [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk)

My new set up:

```
Slow client (10.2.0.7) \
                        \
                        Nginx (10.2.0.5) <===> PythonApp (10.2.0.4, port 8000)
                       /
                      /
Fast client (10.2.0.6)
```

You can reference this [Digital Ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04) to set up Flask app
Python App:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

@app.route("/big-file")
def big_file():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>" + "Hello There!"*1000000 + "</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Slow client:

```
# modprobe ifb
# ip link set dev ifb0 up
# tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
# tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: \
protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
# tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root netem delay 750ms
```

Run wrk test on fast & slow client:

Slow client:

```
# wrk -t4 -c10 -d30  http://pythonapp.com/big-file
```

Fast client:

```
# wrk -t2 -c100 -d10 http://pythonapp.com
```

It's a must for slow client to access /big-file path, which will return a fairly large response. If the response is smaller than [proxy_buffer_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size), the connection between Nginx and proxied server will be closed very quickly, and you cannot simulate the blocking.

Connections occupied by slow clients under no proxy_buffering in Nginx & throughput of fast clients:
[image: Connections occupied by slow clients]

Throughput of fast clients when no proxy buffering
[image: Test Result of fast client for no proxy buffering]

If there is proxy_buffering, you shall not see connections occupied by slow clients. You can run the commands for slow clients to download slow response first, then check the connections in Nginx.
[image: No occupied connections by slow clients]

Throughput of fast clients when there is proxy buffering
[image]